# Print a product attribute in the product loop with {{post.attribute}} syntax

Tags: timber

I'm trying to print a product attribute in a WooCommerce products loop.

I'm currently doing it this way:

```
{{post.terms('pa_producer-name')|join(', ')}}
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to extend the PostQuery class so that I could have it available as

```
{{post.producer}}
```

Thanks!